# ExifTool - check if all files have the same amount of channels

Tags: metadata, exiftool

I would need your help with ExifTool. I am trying to check if all of my .wav files have the same amount of channels through meta-data. How should I proceed? Should I print out the tags first and then write a script to check if they are all the same or is there a better way?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You want to check "same metadata", or just check "same number of channels"?

Comment: Same number of channels, updated the title

Comment: If you want to compare against a specific number of channels, you can use the [`-if` option](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html#if-NUM-EXPR) like this `-if "$NumChannels==2"` or `-if "$NumChannels>1"` to get a specific list of files that don't meet the criteria.  But exiftool doesn't have a way to compare one file to another.  If you are unsure of the number of channels to start with, you would need to script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to do it externally (via a file or your shell controls or something.

e.g., in bash:

```
if [ "$(exiftool -NUMCHANNELS a.wav)" == "$(exiftool -NUMCHANNELS b.wav)" ]
then
    echo match
fi
```

To see if many files all match, you could do something like

```
exiftool -q -NUMCHANNELS *.wav | uniq | wc -l
```

And verify the output is `1`

Comment: How could I go about this when I have 1000s of files?

Comment: .. in bash? Set a variable to the value for one of the files and then compare that value (in a for loop) to all the files.

Comment: Or you could pipe it all through `uniq` and see if you get more than one line. I'll add that to my answer